# why whan i ragrupped a datatable with groupby not work?

Tags: r

i have a datatable
field id, 2022, 2023
id

| id | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pippo | 4 | 2 |
| lulca | 7 | 3 |
| lulca | 1 | 8 |
| maria | 1 | 3 |

i make create a new column with total for id

```
  cubet <- cubed %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Subtotal = sum(2023)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

but i have a new column with 2023

| id | 2022 | 2023 | Subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pippo | 4 | 2 | 2023 |
| lulca | 7 | 3 | 2023 |
| lulca | 1 | 8 | 2023 |
| maria | 1 | 3 | 2023 |

```
  cubet <- cubed %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Subtotal = sum(2023)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: "2023" is not a valid column name, so you need to backtick it, i.e. ``mutate(Subtotal = sum(`2023`))``

Comment: i have errorr
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `subtotale = sum("2023")`.
ℹ In group 1: `ID = "\"pippo\" "`.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument

the field id contain "pippo"

Comment: Try using backticks instead of quotation marks e.g. `sum(\`2023\`)` instead of `sum("2023")`.

Comment: i use a quotation marks ' sum('2023') but into respond i have  Error in mutate(): ℹ In argument: subtotale = sum("2023"). ℹ In group 1: ID = "\"pippo\" ". Caused by error in sum()

Comment: the problem is when field "id" search a punctuation character, if I remove the "group by" it works without grouping obviously

Comment: Has your issue been solved ? Use ``sum(`2023`)`` instead of `sum('2023')`